# (Over)write a value from a dictionary to a specific column in an already existing excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I have a dictionary `dc_checkboxes` with key value pairs like these: `{0:1, 1:1, 2:0}`. These are {index : binary answer} pairs I get from a checkbox. (Using python and TKinter)

I want to (over)write them to an excel column called "Answers" in an already existing excel file (and there are a bunch of other columns that I don't want to overwrite).

I tried doing this:

```
    import xlsxwriter

    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"C:\Users\Sasha\Documents\OpstartBotsScript\bots.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.get_worksheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    # loop through the dictionary and write to excel
    for key in dc_checkboxes.keys():
        sheet.write(key+2, "Answers", dc_checkboxes[key].value)
```

#key+2 because excel row counts        starts with 1 and the first row is the header

I get the **"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' "** in that last line. But I don't know what exactly is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible reason is there is no sheet named `Sheet1`.

Comment: No no, there is. I checked. :(

Comment: Xlsxwriter can't read or modify an existing file. It can only create new files. That is why there isn't an existing worksheet called 'Sheet1'. The OpenPyXL library can modify existing files.